# Split 10L in half using 4L and 6L jugs

Tags: decanting-problems

You are given 3 jugs:

- a 10L jug (full)
- a 4L jug (empty)
- a 6L jug (empty)

The task is to split the 10L so that there are 5L each in the 10L and 6L jugs, and none in the 4L jug.

Solve or prove that it is impossible.

Comment: Is this an original puzzle?

Comment: It's a modification of one I saw - the original just called for having equal amounts in the 10L and 6L jugs - didn't specify the amount. I had a hunch this modification wasn't possible but I couldn't prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Impossible because

> Every amount you can make is an integer multiple of 2L (which is the greatest common divisor of 10L, 4L, and 6L).